# python heroku syncdb error

Tags: python, django, database, heroku

Disclosure: I have no idea what im doing.

I'm getting the following error. Could not import settings 'mvp_landing.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named dj_database_url

I've looked up this answer and most lead to looking at sys.path files and putting the settings file into one of these paths.

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

^^ I have no idea where these are located or how to move my settings file into one of these paths.

Comment: `Disclosure: I have no idea what im doing.` why did you write this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the `dj_database_url` module using `pip`

Comment: I've run that statement but I still get the same error. This is what my requirements.txt looks like Django==1.6.5 South==1.0.1 django-registration==1.0 dj-database-url==0.3.0 requests==2.4.3 stripe==1.19.1 wsgiref==0.1.2 dj-static==0.0.6 django-toolbelt==0.0.1 gunicorn==19.0.0 psycopg2==2.5.3 static3==0.5.1 –  Bhavik Patel

Answer (score 0):

The error explains exactly what is going on: there is no module named "dj_database_url", which means you have not installed it.

You need to do that by putting that line into your requirements.txt file. If you're running locally, you can do `pip install dj_database_url`.

Comment: I've run that statement but I still get the same error. This is what my requirements.txt looks like Django==1.6.5
South==1.0.1
django-registration==1.0
dj-database-url==0.3.0
requests==2.4.3
stripe==1.19.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
dj-static==0.0.6
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
gunicorn==19.0.0
psycopg2==2.5.3
static3==0.5.1